# SQL Server: query to get the data between two values from same columns and calculate time difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to get the number of hours between two values, say 20 and 25 or above (this will be user input values and not fixed). Below is the table with sample data.

Consider in the table on `01-09-2016 08:40` `value_ID` is `25` and it reaches back to `20` on `02-09-2016 13:20`, I need to consider the number of hours between these two range ie 12 hours and 40 min it is .. Similarly `04-09-2016 13:20` it reached `26.3`  (which is above 25 ) and `'06-09-2016 16:20'` reached `19.3` (below 20) and number of hours is 45 hours. I tried creating a function, however it's not working..

CODE TO CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NumOfHrs](
[ID] [float] NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Value_ID] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

CODE to insert data :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[NumOfHrs]
       ([ID]
       ,[Date]
       ,[Value_ID])
 VALUES
(112233,'8-31-2016 08:20:00',19.2),
(112233,'9-01-2016 08:30:00',24),
(112233,'9-01-2016 08:40:00',25),
(112233,'9-01-2016 09:20:00',26),
(112233,'9-02-2016 10:20:00',27),
(112233,'9-02-2016 10:20:00',24),
(112233,'9-02-2016 10:20:00',23),
(112233,'9-02-2016 11:20:00',22),
(112233,'9-02-2016 12:20:00',21),
(112233,'9-02-2016 13:20:00',20),
(112233,'9-03-2016 13:20:00',19.8),
(112233,'9-04-2016 13:20:00',21),
(112233,'9-04-2016 14:20:00',24),
(112233,'9-04-2016 16:20:00',24.6),
(112233,'9-04-2016 19:20:00',26.3),
(112233,'9-04-2016 23:20:00',27),
(112233,'9-05-2016 00:20:00',22),
(112233,'9-06-2016 16:20:00',19.3),
(112233,'9-07-2016 00:20:00',22),
(112233,'9-08-2016 00:20:00',21),
(112233,'9-09-2016 00:20:00',23),
(445566,'9-10-2016 00:20:00',24),
(445566,'9-11-2016 00:20:00',25),
(445566,'9-12-2016 00:20:00',26),
(445566,'9-13-2016 00:20:00',24),
(445566,'9-14-2016 00:20:00',23),
(445566,'9-15-2016 00:20:00',24),
(445566,'9-16-2016 00:20:00',21),
(445566,'9-17-2016 00:20:00',20),
(445566,'9-18-2016 00:20:00',18.5),
(445566,'9-19-2016 00:20:00',17)
```

image of the table:
[image]

Comment: This is not the correct way to include sample tabular data in your question. Please spend some time to find out how formatting tabular data works here is SO.

Comment: Ok ,Sure I will do that.

Comment: The best way to include sample data is to write it as DDL+DML of the sample table. This way we can copy it to a test environment and check our answers before posting them.

Comment: As per suggestion i have edited and added the DML+DLL query for sample data

Comment: I think you have misused the query I posted. There are no `'ignore'` fields in your output.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes 'Ignore' has been filter out using where clause as you have done for final output in 'NumOfHrs_grp' table ..

Comment: I will be able to help you if you include in textual format a *minimal* set of data that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos  : Given below link shows the issued sample: 
  http://rextester.com/BDIY39239

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos : Given below link shows the issued sample: rextester.com/BDIY39239 –please change the code at the end to "select * from NumOfHrs_grp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I couldn't think of anything simpler. Here's my try to solve the problem:

```
;with NumOfHrs_rn as (
    select id, [Date], Value_ID, 
           row_number() over (partition by id order by [date]) AS rn
    from [dbo].[NumOfHrs] 
), NumOfHrs_lag as (
    select t1.id, t1.[date], 
           t2.Value_ID as prev_value, 
           t1.Value_ID as curr_value           
    from NumOfHrs_rn as t1
    -- get previous value (lag)
    join NumOfHrs_rn as t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.rn = t2.rn + 1 
), NumOfHrs_flag as (
    select id, [Date], prev_value, curr_value, 
           case 
              when curr_value >= 25 and prev_value < 25 then 'start'
              when curr_value <= 20 and prev_value > 20 then 'stop'
              else 'ignore'
           end as flag
    from NumOfHrs_lag
), NumOfHrs_grp as ( 
    select id, [Date], curr_value, flag,
           row_number() over (partition by id order by [Date]) -
           case flag
              when 'start' then 0
              when 'stop' then 1
           end as grp
    from NumOfHrs_flag
    where flag in ('start', 'stop')
)
select min([Date]) AS 'start', max([Date]) as 'stop'
from NumOfHrs_grp
group by id, grp
order by min([Date])
```

**Output:**

```
start                    stop
------------------------------------------------
2016-09-01 08:40:00.000  2016-09-02 13:20:00.000
2016-09-04 19:20:00.000  2016-09-06 16:20:00.000
2016-09-11 00:20:00.000  2016-09-17 00:20:00.000
```

You can manipulate the above query in order to get the time difference expressed in hours/minutes/seconds format.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/PPZ53703)

Comment: Thanks .. Thats great effort... I was breaking by head for this logic from morning!!!! However this works perfectly fine when start time and end time is in date column chronological order ,but ours is random data ORDER BY clause can not be used in the CTE is what I understand..Hence column GRP in my data table output is not grouping based on Single Start and End as it happens in the example code.. Its giving grp number for each and every flag values individually.. I am Adding screenshot in the question for your reference...Kindly help!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @NischeyAnand You don't need to use `ORDER BY` inside the CTE. You just use in the `OVER` clause of `ROW_NUMBER`. Can you setup a rextester demo with the issue?

Comment: Over clause I have used as guided by you in the code.I will try rextester demo in sometime.. Thanks.

Comment: Given below link shows the issued sample: rextester.com/BDIY39239 –